# CSS height, How to get it to go around inner divs

Tags: html, css

Why is it that my border does not go around my inner divs, and my inner div borders do not go to the bottom of the outer div, ( in FF but need this for all major browser).

Can someone please help

```
<div id="main">
    <div class="insidediv">
        <p>Article 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="insidediv">
        <p>Article 2</p>

    </div>
    <div class="insidediv">
<p>Article 3</p>
    </div>
</div>

#main{
    width: 800px;
    height: 100%;
    border: 20px solid black;
}

.insidediv{
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: 20px solid black;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: "inner div borders do not go to the bottom of the outer div" - you need heaps more content for the inner border to reach bottom of the outer div. Try putting lots of sample content inside <p>lots of content</p>.

Comment: @YogeshNath lets add a ship to this content - maybe that'll help? or any other ideas?

Comment: @AdityaSaxena - Sarcasm. How does your comment add something useful to the post?

Comment: Can anyone help me with the other side of this problem that YogeshNath has said, as I can not add lots of content to the second inner div just to get the border right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alter #main to `float: left;` or `overflow:hidden`. I recommend the float

Answer (score 0):

Set `overflow: hidden;` on `#main`.

Edit: [demo](http://cssdeck.com/labs/edstlgzw/0)

Comment: The other borders are not extending down when you enter content in to just one of the inner divs.

Answer (score 0):

Floating elements takes them out of the normal flow of the document, meaning their container no longer understands where they end for lack of a more technical explanation. To solve the issue you need to clear the float after the last inner div by adding an element with clear:both applied.  http://jsfiddle.net/calder12/BcqnE/

```
<div id="main">
<div class="insidediv">
    <p>Article 1</p>
</div>
<div class="insidediv">
    <p>Article 2</p>

</div>
<div class="insidediv">
<p>Article 3</p>
</div><div class="clear"</div>
</div>

#main{
width: 800px;
height: 100%;
border: 20px solid black;
}

.insidediv{
width: 200px;
height: 100%;
border-right: 20px solid black;
float:left;
}
.clear{clear:both;}
```

There is also the clearfix method which is similar to the above but the more standard approach these days. http://j.mp/bestclearfix

Comment: I would recommend the use of [.clearfix](http://j.mp/bestclearfix) instead of this hack.

Comment: Clearfix is more common but I wouldn't call clearing this way a hack any more than I would call clearfix a hack. They're both legitimate solutions. Notice the second to last rule in your solution? Wonder why it's in that position? hmmm.

Comment: I didn't mean "hack" in the derogatory sense. Clearfix is just a more elegant solution.

Comment: none of them are hacks - clear and float always go together - infact clearfix is kind of a utility that takes clear:both to the next level implementing it in all browsers.

Comment: True and fair enough, added the clearfix link to the bottom of my answer so the OP is aware of it as well.

Comment: The other borders are not extending down when you enter content in to just one of the inner divs.